# Excel/VBA - How to create a function which returns a list

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a function in Excel which returns a list. The reason behind it is:

In my workbook I am using SUMIFS. There are drop downs where user picks the criterias which are then passed to SUMIFS as arguments. To give an example let's say that I have a drop down in cell A1 and the possible values are: `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"`. My formula is:

```
=SUMIFS(sumRange,criteriaRange,A1)
```

Assume I would like to add two more items to the drop downs: "All vowels" (so `"A"` and `"E"`) and "All consonants" (so `"B", "C", "D", "F"`). I found a way to give alternative conditions in SUMIFS by wrapping it up with SUM and providing a list of elements in SUMIFS like in the examples below:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(sumRange,criteriaRange,{"A","E"})  
=SUM(SUMIFS(sumRange,criteriaRange,{"B", "C", "D", "F"})
```

Now I would like to substitute the lists above with a function (f) which would take the value of A1 as an argument and return:
`{"A","E"}` - when A1 is "All vowels"
`{"B", "C", "D", "F"}` - when A1 is "All consonants"
identity in all other cases.
At the end I would like the below formula to work:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(sumRange,criteriaRange,f(A1)}
```

for any choice in A1. Is it possible?
I tried different approaches, like returning an array, or returning a string `"{"A","E"}"`. None of those did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add an extra level of calculation. This can be done by entering your `SUM(SUMIFS(...))` as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> or substituting the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) for the [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) wrapper that totals the iterations as the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) loops through the OR elements in the criteria.

**Sample UDF:**

```
Function ma(sCRIT As String)
    Select Case LCase(sCRIT)
        Case "all vowels"
            ma = Array("A", "E")
        Case "all consonants"
            ma = Array("B", "C", "D", "F")
        Case Else
            ma = sCRIT 
    End Select
End Function
```

**Sample worksheet:**

[image: UDF returning an array]

The *array formula* in F5 that returns the correct result is,

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(D1:D6, C1:C6, ma(A1)))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered correctly, they can be copied or filled right/down to alternate locations like any other formula (subject to relative/absolute cell range addressing).

The *standard formula* in F6 that returns the correct result is,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(D1:D6, C1:C6, ma(A1)))
```

The SUMPRODUCT function provides that extra layer of processing that your formula requires without the use of CSE.

Both the array formula w/ CSE and the SUMPRODUCT can still use non-array, single criteria without penalty if you expand the `Select Case` of the UDF..